Display cart Item custom download URL on WooCommerce Cart page
I ask the customers to upload a PDF file for each product being added to the cart, and need to display the file download URL for each cart item. It appears that WooCommerce strips HTML tags and doesn't allow displaying URLs. All I see is just the label "download" for each cart item.  The view source code from cart doesn't show any URL.
Here is my plugin file:
add_filter('woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_custom_data_in_cart', 10, 2);
function display_custom_data_in_cart($item_data, $cart_item) {
    if (!empty($cart_item['rx_type'])) {
        $item_data[] = array(
            'name' => 'RX Type Details',
            'value' => $cart_item['rx_type']
        );
        error_log('RX Type Details: ' . $cart_item['rx_type']);
    }
    if (!empty($cart_item['calculations'])) {
        $item_data[] = array(
            'name' => 'Cost per Lens',
            'value' => '$' . number_format($cart_item['calculations'], 2)
        );
        error_log('Calculations: ' . $cart_item['calculations']);
    }
    if (!empty($cart_item['uploaded_file_url'])) {
        $item_data[] = array(
            'name' => 'Uploaded Prescription',
            'value' => esc_html($cart_item['uploaded_file_url']) // Display the URL as plain text
        );
        error_log('Uploaded Prescription URL: ' . $cart_item['uploaded_file_url']);
    } else {
        error_log('No uploaded file URL found in cart item data.');
    }
    return $item_data;
}

I tried removing wp_kses_post function call in cart-item-data.php template file, but it did not make any difference.
How I can display a download URL for cart items in WooCommerce Cart page?
